Google sheets: How to merge two Google sheets with duplicate keys?
I have two sheets, each containing a table with duplicate keys. I want to create a third sheet that merges these two tables such that each row represents a cross-product of the data for each key.
Here's an example of my data:
Sheet1:



Key
Data




A
1


B
2


C
3


A
4


D
5



Sheet2:



Key
Data




B
6


C
7


D
8


A
9


A
10



I want to create a third sheet that looks like this:
Merged:



Key
Data (Sheet1)
Data (Sheet2)




A
1
9


A
1
10


A
4
9


A
4
10


B
2
6


C
3
7


D
5
8



How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance
I have been trying an INDEX and MATCH combination, but given that keys are duplicated I only obtain the first value.

I put everything in one sheet, so it's more easily viewable, please adapt the range so it represents the two sheets:
=LET(keys,TOCOL(UNIQUE(A2:A),1),
REDUCE(HSTACK("Key","Data1","Data2"),keys,LAMBDA(a,key,
  VSTACK(a,REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=key),LAMBDA(b,each1,
  VSTACK(b,BYROW(FILTER(E2:E,D2:D=key),LAMBDA(each2,  HSTACK(key,each1,each2))))))))))



Could you extend the formula to add a third table? I have been trying to figure it out but I cannot manage to do it. Thanks in advance
